# Recover files from flash drive which keeps reconecting itself?

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, data-recovery

I have flash drive which was not connected to PC for long time. When connected file explorer displays all files but trying to copy some of those files fails (Probably due to charge decay in flash drive cell).

Some of the files are still recoverable.

What makes it harder is that when windows tries to copy corrupted files I get an following error:

[image]

What happens actually is that drive reconnects itself at that point which explains the error.

I am even unable to run `chkdsk /r /f` because flash drive keeps reconnecting itself.

My current solution is to copy all files, when error happens(At this point flash reconnects itself, mentioned error appears) I wait for drive to reconnect, skip the corrupted file.
Obviously this is very slow process due to the fact that drive contains a lot of files.

How to recover all files in this case?

Comment: Try connecting it to your PC via a USB hub. Sounds honestly like the drive is dying. Or perhaps even a powered USB hub if somehow the disconnects are power related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The disk is obviously almost dead.

Try first the disk on every USB port and computer that you have, in the hope
of finding one port that works better.

If this doesn't work out,
you could try the deep-freeze remedy, which is to wrap up the disk very well against
moisture and put it in the deep-freeze for an hour or more.
This sometimes helps, but not always, and is said to be a one-shot method.

You could also try to use
[Roadkil's Unstoppable Copier](https://roadkil.net/program.php/P29/Unstoppable%20Copier).
The
[documentation](https://www.roadkil.net/support.php?AppID=Unstoppable%20Copier&VersionID=5.2)
mentions a batch mode and a setting that you may turn off for
"Resume Partial Files", so as not to
resume the transfer of a file that was interrupted.
I haven't actually used this tool, but it has good reviews.

Comment: I tried suggested application and managed to recover some files easily, although flash drive still kept reconnecting itself.

Comment: How would the “deep-freeze remedy” work for a flash drive? In only heard of that being useful on old hard disk drives from the early 1990s to prior.

Comment: @JakeGould: It was never explained why freeze helped hard disks. If this pertains to the mechanical parts then it doesn't apply here, but if it helps with the electrical circuits or contacts then it may apply. In any case, this is a desperate solution when everything else has failed.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the USB mass storage controller (the integrated circuit) on your flash drive is defective.  While the NAND flash memory can go bad, that would only result in a read or write error.  Those cells would be marked as bad and stored in the flash memory.  However, when you attempt to read certain cells, the drive is disconnecting from the computer, which is not normal behavior.  This indicates a failure in the circuitry of the IC, causing a short or under-voltage.

Can the files be recovered?  If the memory itself isnt damaged, then the files might be able to be recovered.  The data might be able to be read, but still could be corrupted.  This would require replacing the USB mass storage controller, or moving the flash memory to another device.

If the files are important, your best bet would be to send it off to a drive recovery shop.  They have the proper knowledge and equipment to perform the task.  You could attempt to do it yourself, but if the data is important, would you want to risk permanently losing it?